# Book class problem with appendix and toc

Tags: table-of-contents, book-class

I am trying to build a latex template equivalent to our university's word template. I've fixed everything except an issue with the appendices.

I want the appendix chapters to look like this:

[image]

But when it does, their TOC input for the appendices comes all jumbled up like this (look last line):

[image]

If I remove the "APPENDIX" in front of the roman number in the \thechapter command, then it's OK. But I need it.

Here is a minimum working example. I want to keep the way that the chapters are printed on the same line while the appendix chapters in two lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\parskip 0.4em
\usepackage{etoc}      
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=16cm, top=2.0cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=1.25cm, includehead, includefoot}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{1em}{} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{25em}
{\LARGE \textbf{Doctoral dissertation} \\}
\vspace{5em}
{\huge \textbf{Fancy title}\\}
\vspace{5em}
{\LARGE \textbf{Fancy name}\\}
\vfill {\Large \textbf{City, Month Year}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{lalal}
\section{lalal}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{lalal}
\section{lalal}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{APPENDIX \Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter }{0pt}{\huge} 
\chapter{Title of appendix I}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\numberline` is trying to cram "Appendix I" into a small space reserved fot the chapter number.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\addtocontents` to modify `\numberline` in the middle of the TOC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

%\usepackage{tocloft}
\parskip 0.4em
\usepackage{etoc}      
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=16cm, top=2.0cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=1.25cm, includehead, includefoot}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{1em}{} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\makeatletter
\def\bignumberline#1{\advance\@tempdima by 7em
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{25em}
{\LARGE \textbf{Doctoral dissertation} \\}
\vspace{5em}
{\huge \textbf{Fancy title}\\}
\vspace{5em}
{\LARGE \textbf{Fancy name}\\}
\vfill {\Large \textbf{City, Month Year}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{lalal}
\section{lalal}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{lalal}
\section{lalal}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline=\string\bignumberline}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{APPENDIX \Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter }{0pt}{\huge} 


\chapter{Title of appendix I}



\end{document}
```